# Google Chrome Font Rendering (Bold & Jittery)

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, rendering

I know there is a total flood of font rendering related questions on all sorts of sites these days. One of them should provide me with an answer, so you would think. However much I search I cannot seem to find a solution for my problem though.

In `google chrome` almost all fonts are displayed bold. Well that wouldn't really be the end of the world. What bugs me even more is, that they are rendered very jittery. As in they look sort of distorted.

I have made a picture to show the difference between my `firefox` and `chrome` font rendering:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYRh4.png

I simply want to get rid of this. It has been bothering me for a while and no solution I can find on the web helps.

For the record I have uninstalled and reinstalled `chrome`. Also I have disabled `Direct Write` in the `chrome://flags`.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually not a rendering problem, but a font loading problem. Firefox shows Arial (a font optimized for rendering at small sizes), while Chrome shows Helvetica (which is not, at least your installed version).

The editor from your screenshot probably asks for the font Helvetica and, if Helvetica is not available, Arial and other sans-serif fonts. I assume you only have the Bold version of Helvetica installed on your computer. It actually should display the Regular version, but it isn't available.
Firefox therefore falls back on Arial, while Chrome shows the closest weight you do have: the Bold version.

To fix your problem, you should try uninstalling Helvetica Bold (through Control Panel > Fonts). Note it can also go by other names such as Helvetica Neue, Helvetica LT Std, Neue Helvetica, etc. Don't forget to restart just to be sure. Then Chrome should also show the optimized Arial.

Comment: I don't have this problem anymore ever since I re-installed windows completely. So this must be right.

Comment: Thank you! I first had this problem after updating Chrome (v. 48.0.2564.116 m) - turned all text bold. This fixed my problem, it was Neue that had to go.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough the question is kind of old, the "problem" may still occur and I found another scenario which causes this text-appearance to happen (which, honestly, brought me here).

In my case, I did not note that my jQuery callback loops and renders the text multiple times to a fix position, about 20 times. I checked the entire css. font-family, text-rendering (geometricPrecision in this scenario), font-weight and what not.

It took me quite a while to figure out that I had 20 divs over each other with the same text, because I've got a very complex and deeply encapsulated DOM there.

So if you ever get here with similar problems, you may also want to check for this one.

The easiest way to check is, to delete the element holding the text using the browser integrated inspector / developer tools (Windows: <kbd>F12</kbd>, Mac: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) - navigate to "Elements", toggle the left icon (that one with the cursor symbol in it) to blue (active), click the element in your browser. It should be highlighted under "Elements" now, easiest way to find it in the DOM. Right-Click and delete it. If you still see the text, you've most likely got multiple overlays while you only wanted one.

Answer (score -1):

I just want to say that I resolved this issue by deleting a whole Roboto Font Family from the system. (MacOS Big Sur 11.2 (20D64).